# Как обнулить счетчик Id в Entity Framework?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Добавляю в базу несколько записей, соответственно генерируется Id=1,2,3,4...
Затем удаляю все записи, и начинаю снова добавлять генерируется Id=5,6,7...
Как можно обнулить счетчик Id?

Comment: это не фишка EF, это функционал вашей БД

Comment: Это уникальный идентификатор, он не должен начинать отсчет заново.

Comment: Ну в MS SQL есть команда на сброс счетчика. Однако не понимаю, как вам мешает то, что идентификаторы начинаются не с 1. Они растут не только при вставках, но так же, если вставка обломилась с ошибкой.

Comment: Если вам нужно удалить всю информацию из базы и начать с чистого листа, попробуйте использовать команды `db.Database.EnsureDeleted();` и `db.Database.EnsureCreated();`

Comment: [`ALTER TABLE tablename AUTO_INCREMENT = 1`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8923132/12888024)

Comment: Id - он не для людей, он для машины. Оставьте компьютеру компьютерово, а сами занимайтесь творчеством, а не выравниванием циферок

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```cs
context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(@"SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[TableName] ON");
context.SaveChanges();
context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(@"SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[TableName] OFF");
```

при обновлении БД нужны команды `IDENTITY_INSERT` они позволяют счетчику из указанной таблицы принимать те значения которые были пропущены из-за удаления кортежей.